# I want to make multiple namespaces based on the URL but I'm confused socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, namespaces

user can access namespace like nsp1 by hitting localhost:3000/nsp1
the same with nsp2, I want to create them dynamically with a name entered from text box 
but for now I tried to make just one namespace using code below but the server hits error *Cannot GET /my-namespace*

server.js

```
var io  = require('socket.io')(http, { path: '/my-namespace'});

io
.of('/my-namespace')
.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected with id %s', socket.id);

    socket.on('my-message', function (data) {
        io.of('my-namespace').emit('my-message', data);
        // or socket.emit(...)
        console.log('broadcasting my-message', data);
    });
});
```

client.js

```
   var socket = io('localhost:3000/my-namespace', { path: '/my-namespace'});
```

Comment: You should look into `rooms` [[link](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)] for that purpose.

Comment: Agree with Brahma.  Dynamic things like this should probably be rooms, not namespaces.

Comment: would you give me the complete code for it, I tried the code on the documentation but it doesn't work @BrahmaDev

Comment: Pretty related to this question by same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122290/how-to-make-the-user-enter-a-specific-room-by-typing-its-name-int-the-url-sock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);
app.get("/contact.html", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/contact.html');
});
app.get("/login.html", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/login.html');
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});
app.get(/(^\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$)/, function (req, res) {
    //Matches anything with alphabets,numbers and hyphen without trailing slash
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/room.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected with id %s', socket.id);

    socket.on('join', function (room) {
        //May be do some authorization
        socket.join(room);
        console.log(socket.id, "joined", room);
    });
    socket.on('leave', function (room) {
        //May be do some authorization
        socket.leave(room);
        console.log(socket.id, "left", room);
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function (data) {
        //May be do some authorization
        io.to(data.room).emit("chat message", data.message);
    });
});
```

room.html/client.js

```
var socket = io('localhost:3000');
socket.emit("join",location.pathname);
socket.emit("chat message",{room:location.pathname, message:<val>});
```

Comment: but I need to make the user enter a specific room by hitting it's name in the url like localhost:3000/room1
 then socket.join("room1") can I do that using socket.io or I have to do some code @Brahma

Comment: You don't need a separate namespace for each room.

Comment: Got it. You'll need something like expressjs.com for that. Socket.io doesn't do that.

Comment: @shrouk-mansour How are you serving your frontend right now ?

Comment: I'm serving using nodejs, I used your code and typed this url(localhost:3000/room1) but I got this error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'E:\work\MT\chat-example2\room.html'
    at Error (native)

Comment: I placed  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/room.html'); with  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html'); and it worked :"D, now I'm sending in multible rooms very well but why you said can not with socket.io, I tried this line bit it gives me undefined when I try to use in the function
        socket.emit('chat message', {path:location.pathname, msg: $('#m').val()} );
,  Is there any thing wrong !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154020/discussion-between-shrouk-mansour-and-brahma-dev).

Comment: This design means you can never have any other pages on your site since all URLs are interpreted as a room name.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, it doesn't stop you from adding more routes before the one for the room. They'll work perfectly fine.

Comment: @BrahmaDev -  Yeah, but that would be a screwy design where some words go to chat rooms and some words don't.

Comment: @jfriend00 That depends. Perhaps there might not be a need for any other page. Just a home page at / and  wildcard rooms. We are trying to solve a problem described, not build a product that I know nothing about.

Comment: @jfriend00 I suggested a safe enough way to solve the problem. The regex only allows alphabets and numbers for rooms, any other path like '/contact.html' won't match. Thinking further would just be speculation.

Comment: I don't mean to be arguing against your answer, but do mean to be providing feedback to the OP about the possible limitations or confusion about this type of design.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can see that. That's why I am adding information so it's clear to the OP. The design does allows any numbers of non-room urls as long as they don't match the regex.